# What do "position.transform" and "Input.GetAxis" mean in Unity?

Tags: unity

I am making the transition from Game Maker to Unity, but I feel lost when I look at Unity's programming.

When I followed a tutorial to make basic movements, I had this code:

```
public Vector3 playerPos;
void Update ()
{
    float V_X = transform.position.x;
    V_X += Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") / 2;
    playerPos = new Vector3(V_X, 0, 0);
    transform.position = playerPos;
}
```

A few things are confusing me here:

- What is `transform`? And why is `position` something that is a part of it? Why not have the position of the objects represented by just `x` rather than `transform.position.x`?
- Is `GetAxis(...)` a command that has a return value? Why is in "sub-categorized" under `Input`? And why not detect the key presses directly?

Comment: isn't your confusion caused by their choice to use an Entity Component System ? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity_component_system

Comment: I looked up ECS, is that just a way of using C#? So the conventions are inherent to C# rather than Unity?

Comment: Certainly not ! C# works like java, or C++ in the way it's intended to be used as a base. I would say ECS is a total perversion of object oriented programming. Not that I don't like it, but it's pushing the boundaries for sure !

Comment: I have only worked with high-level programming so I am not very familiar with things like C# or java, I just had the feeling that ECS is only a way of using these low-level programs without making changes to the low level programs themselves, in which case I would have to learn C# or java 101 to understand ECS, but you seem to suggest otherwise?

Comment: That's right ! ECS is a way to add fields at run time. Because fields are registered in a dynamic container. (field = property or member)

Comment: Many of your initial questions are basic, how-to-program-C# kinds of questions. These aren't game development specific and thus aren't on topic here, so I've removed them to try and make the question as on-topic as possible (focusing entirely on what certain parts of Unity's API do). I suggest you look for a good reference or tutorials on the C# programming language, though, as it will help you quite a bit to have some basic understanding of the language when exploring Unity.

Answer (score 2):

Well, your first question should be categorised as General question rather than Unity's specific question.

> What is transform? And why is position something that is a part of it? Why not have the position of the objects represented by just x rather than transform.position.x?

There is a term in Computer Graphics called **Transformation** which includes 3 basic attributes of object.

- Translation
- Rotation
- Scaling

**Translation** is you can say the movement of an object. For example an object at position (10,10) and when you move it by some amount and that object's new position becomes (20,10) then you can say that your object is *translated* by (10,0) and the mathematical operation used is *Addition*

Bit similar case is with **Scaling** (with *Multiplication*) and **Rotation** (with both *Multiplication* with sin and cos, and *Addition* ).

Have a look in detail [here](https://www.cs.uic.edu/~jbell/CourseNotes/ComputerGraphics/2DTransforms.html)

Now in Unity the component which represents the *transformation* of an object called [Transform](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.html), by which you can change all three basic attributes i.e. **Translation**, **Rotation** and **Scaling**.

Now your second question, that is,

> Is GetAxis(...) a command that has a return value? Why is in "sub-categorized" under Input? And why not detect the key presses directly?

What I can say is just the will of Unity Engine Developers. They retain it and so many more different methods in class called [Input](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.html), which is the part of UnityEngine. To be very honest I can't give you the exact reason for that. May be someone with have more knowledge about it may answer your this question in more detail.

Answer (score 1):

> why do I need to use things like "public" and "float" to declare variables? Where are the variables stored? In Game Maker the variables are specific to the instances or the objects, but in Unity I am not sure if the variables in the scripts are stored in the gameObjects that has the script as a component or what.

Those are access modifiers and data types and don't relate specifically to game development. Unity is strongly-typed and uses inheritance. This is fundamental and I suggest holding off on exploring Unity until you have a working knowledge of it. A basic C# primer should get you on your way.

> Is GetAxis(...) a command that has a return value? Why is in "sub-categorized" under "Input"? and why not detect the key presses directly?

It is a public member of the Input class which does all of the grunt-work processing low-level inputs into higher-level "events" and functions. GetAxis() returns the value of a virtual axis. This is how you can use "D", mouse X+, and joystick X+ to produce the same result (move the player right). Each device has different ways of representing "left" and "right" but they can all be mapped to a 1D coordinate system (vaguely %-like). If the keyboard is the source of input, the value is -1, 0, or 1, because you can't "half push" a keyboard button; they are on or off. If the joystick was the source, the values could be anywhere in-between, because the device, itself, is analog. The script does not require deltaTime as an arugment because GetAxis() is already frame-rate independent (done by the Input class). The -1:1 scale makes it convenient for multiplication with a fixed direction; in other words, "move right -1" is equivalent to "move left" while "move right +1" actually moves right.

> what is "transform"? and why is "position" something that is a part of it? Why not have the position of the objects represented by just x rather than transform.position.x

The "position" of an object describes the relationship between the object and an arbitrary origin (relative translation/movement only). However, objects in 3D-space are frequently scaled, rotated, and translated in varying combinations and degrees. The "transform" represents a specific combination of all 3 (a world matrix) and fully orients an object's "local space" in "world space". An object may be transformed through many spaces (by many Transforms) before even getting to the view and projection stages. The Earth orbits the sun, and the moon orbits Earth; the moon requires two transforms to correctly position it relative to the sun and earth.

If you go to the unity documentation for MonoBehavior (the class your script inherits from), you'll find that transform is "inherited" (from Behavior). If you click on Behavior, you'll see that transform is, again, inherited. If you click on Component, you'll find transform under "Variables" and is not inherited. The type of transform is the Transform class and it is public member of Component, and so, inherited by your script. The transform that "belongs" to this script, can be referenced by other components; for example, the player object. The script updates the transform which the object, then, uses. If you assign this script to multiple objects, they will all respond to the user's input. The Transform class also has many helper functions for converting many types of inputs between local- and world-space.

> what is the difference between new Vector3(...) and just reassigning the variables?

There are *technical* differences, but I don't think that's what you mean and you are correct that:

```
playerPos.x = V_x;
playerPos.y = 0;
playerPos.z = 0;
```

is equivalent.

Comment: Components are things you can attach to a game object. Coincidentally, you can remove them too. The only exception (usually) is a Transform, as a GameObject requires a transform to make sense. There are two kinds: 3D (Transform) and 2D (RectTransform, which is a subclass of Transform). Sometimes components will require other components, such as the FirstPersonController requiring a CharacterMotor. So you can only remove the latter after removing the former, while attaching the former will automatically attach the latter.

Answer (score 0):

The `transform` variable is *probably* an instance of [the `Transform` type](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.html). You don't show the declaration of the variable in your code, but it's pretty safe bet.

`Transform` is a type that's used to represent a position, rotation and scale in Unity. It's a representation of a [transformation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix), which we use in 3D graphics environments like Unity to capture those three basic ways of manipulating some object (moving it around, orienting it, and making it bigger or smaller, respectively).

Unity (and many other APIs) wrap position, rotation and scale up into a single type like `Transform` for a few reasons, but one of them is that it makes it easier to pass that information around. Rather than storing 9 to 11 individual floats (and also having to pass all 9 to 11 of them around to various functions), we pack them into one to save time, typing and sanity.

[`Input.GetAxis`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetAxis.html) is indeed a function that returns a value. It's what is known as a "static" function, one that can be called without an instance of the containing type (which is the `Input` type in this case). Static functions are often used in C# where you would use free or "regular" functions elsewhere, because C# doesn't have the concept of functions that exist at the global scope. They all must be inside a class.

`GetAxis` is being used here to get a mouse input here, not a key, so that's why you don't "get the keys directly." However, the reason it's written like this is primarily to provide an *abstraction*, a way to hide underlying potentially-irrelevant details from you so that you can only be concerned with what you actually care about. In this case such an abstraction might have been written so that you could easily be reading the "horizontal" input axis from a joystick or gamepad's analog stick instead, or so the actual input axis requested could be specified via a variable instead of hard-coded like it is in the example, et cetera. It's simply a (reasonably common) design decision Unity decided to make and part of how their API is built.